# Error Msg "Domado: canvas drawImage not yet implemented" in Google Apps Script - drawImage Not Allowed?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-apps-script, draw

I'm getting the error message:

```
"Domado: canvas drawImage not yet implemented"
```

in the browser console when using code in Apps Script that will work otherwise in the browser.

Here is HTML and Javascript code that works, and does what I want.  The same code will not work in Apps Script HTML Service.

### HTML

```
<button onmouseup="fncDrawNewImage()">Put Image Into Canvas</button>
<span style='color:red'>NOTE: Large Image.  Scroll Down to see New Image<span>
    <br/>
    <br>
<img id='rawUploadImg' src="https://c63b5816896b8b38120d71a4eb99978894a5ef14.googledrive.com/host/0B52YKjuEE44ySkhPUTBsbW5sSWM/F28_003537_KPQQAPSQQQQQT0Bw_A.JPG">
<canvas id="cnvsForFormat" width="400" height="226"></canvas>
```

### JavaScript

```
window.fncDrawNewImage = function () {
    window.img = document.getElementById("rawUploadImg");
    var cnvs = document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");
    var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
    cnvs.style.border = "1px solid #c3c3c3";
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 226);
};
```

[jsFiddle put IMG into a CANVAS with drawImage](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/76Mfz/)

In Apps Script, every line works except for:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 226);
```

Is `drawImage` not allowed, or not implemented yet in Apps Script HTML Service?  When an image is drawn in a canvas, the image size can be decreased.  That's what I'm trying to accomplish.  If anyone know how I can decrease the image size in Apps Script I would sure like to know.  (NOT decrease the DISPLAY size in HTML, decrease the actual byte size)

I'm wondering if I can send the image file to `.gs` code, convert it to a string, send it back and then put it into a canvas or an image tag?

Comment: I ran into this problem trying to convert an image toDataURL() in canvas from the context of a Google Docs add-on. Looks like Google haven't implemented it yet in Caja: https://codereview.appspot.com/9698043/diff/3001/src/com/google/caja/plugin/domado.js#newcode4908

Comment: Things have changed.  See new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script now has a new sandboxMode called IFRAME:

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Compress Image')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
};
```

It now allows `ctx.drawImage()`

```
<form>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="fncChangeSize(this.files[0], newWidth, newHeight)" >
</form>

<canvas id="cnvsForFormat" width="400" height="266" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3"></canvas>

<script>
  window.fncChangeSize = function(imageData, newWidth, newHeight) {
    console.log("fncChangeSize ran: " + frmData);

    var cnvs=document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");

    var img = new Image;
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageData);
    var ctx=cnvs.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, newWidth, newHeight);
  };
</script>
```

[Mozilla documentation - drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)